# add intel driver module to initram for pxeboot

Tags: kernel, initramfs, pxe, module

I'm triying to boot [system-rescue-cd](http://www.system-rescue-cd.org/) via pxe.

The Problem on the actual system is, the driver for the network card (intel 82574L) e1000e is not in the initram.igz file, so the system can boot the kernel (rescue64) and the initram, but after the initialization of it, it's missing the driver.

I tried to repack the initram.igz as described in [their website](http://www.system-rescue-cd.org/manual/Build_a_custom_SystemRescueCd_with_your_own_kernel/), with the module existing on a booted systemrescuecd (/lib/modules/4.14.80-std532-amd64/kernel/drivers/net/ethernet/intel/e1000e/e1000e.ko), but after this, the initram.igz did not initialize.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

There is a link from /lib/modules/"Kernel-version" ->/lib64/modules/"Kernel-version"

I couldn't get the link to work in initrd so copied it into a /lib64/modules directory as I was in a rush. There is also a dependency on the ptp module.

It confused me as they use an embedded initrd in the kernel file. 
They used to have the e1000e driver in the older versions of systemrescuecd